# Handling entity updated,removed event in Datacontext ! silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datacontext, odata, wcf-data-services

I have created a datacontext in my silverlight app which utilized "WCF dataservices" to pull out data from custom Odata repository which in turn takes the values from an XML file, the XML file values keep changing since they represent live data, so the question is :

1) when the original data values change can this be reflected automatically on the context ! (I'm implementing "INotifyPropertyChanged" in the mapped class in the WCF service, but still no effect !)

2) when a record is deleted from the original XML, the context records will not be affected until I clear the data and reload them again !.

anyone can help me with this !

Answer (score 0):

The WCF Data Services client needs to query the OData service to get the new values if the original data values are changed/deleted. 
DataServiceCollection  implements INotifyPropertyChanged to alert the context when objects are added to or removed from the collection, but it is not aware of any original service data changes on the service side.
Hope this helps.